# Python Gzip - Appending to file on the fly

Tags: python, gzip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible to append to a gzipped text file on the fly using Python ?

Basically I am doing this:-

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'a', 9)
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

A line is appended (note "appended") to the file every 6 seconds or so, but the resulting file is just as big as a standard uncompressed file (roughly 1MB when done).

Explicitly specifying the compression level does not seem to make a difference either.

If I gzip an existing uncompressed file afterwards, it's size comes down to roughly 80kb.

Im guessing its not possible to "append" to a gzip file on the fly and have it compress ?

Is this a case of writing to a String.IO buffer and then flushing to a gzip file when done ?

Comment: For the gzip algorithm to work efficiently, it has to get its hands on the entire content to be compressed. Otherwise, you're just appending chunks of gzipped content that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Nadh so I guess my last line is correct ? Write to a String.IO and flush to gzip ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You just have to make sure that all content is gzipped together at any instant.

Comment: I vaguely remember that zlib can be used to perform streaming compression, i.e. without seeing all the data in advance.

Comment: The problem is appending only one line of data at once.  For gzip to work efficiently, it needs at least *some* amount of data at once --- not necessarily the whole file, but certainly more than one line.  If sending the whole file at once is too much, you can also send it pieces of 16KB or something.

Comment: Assuming this is a pre-processing of data, can you append that line right before processing the data. That is, instead of open gzip -> write -> close -> open gzip -> process, do open gzip -> read -> add one line -> process

Comment: note that your snippet doesn't work in python 3 unless you add the `t` attribute (text mode).

Answer (score 19):

That works in the sense of creating and maintaining a valid gzip file, since the gzip format permits concatenated gzip streams.

However it doesn't work in the sense that you get lousy compression, since you are giving each instance of gzip compression so little data to work with.  Compression depends on taking advantage the history of previous data, but here gzip has been given essentially none.

You could either a) accumulate at least a few K of data, many of your lines, before invoking gzip to add another gzip stream to the file, or b) do something much more sophisticated that appends to a single gzip stream, leaving a valid gzip stream each time and permitting efficient compression of the data.

You find an example of b) in C, in [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c).  I do not believe that Python has all of the interfaces to zlib needed to implement gzlog directly in Python, but you could interface to the C code from Python.

Comment: b) can be achieved if you're ok with the python process remaining active: just open the gzip file and leave it open (use `with` or close it in a `finally` clause).
You might want to flush regularly, but I'm not sure what that'd do to compression efficiency?

Comment: @drevicko That doesn't do b), since it does not produce a valid gzip stream until it is closed. But, yes, that can be used for an ongoing transmission. Leaving it open does nothing to degrade the compression, but data will come out the other end only occasionally, and in large burst. Flushing will degrade compression, depending on how often it's done. If you do it every line, then it will pretty much not compress at all, or expand. It was that experience that motivated the original question.